# Syntax problem: Streaming GNSS Data from u-blox LEA-6H using str2str of RTKLIB not possible

Tags: gps, linux, rtklib

Im trying to readout the data from my ublox LEA-6H recever over RTKLIB's  `str2str` command-line user interface (CUI). Im using rtkkib_2.4.2 on ubuntu 16.04.02 and the ublox receiver is connected over usb. im trying the following

`sudo ./str2str -in serial://ttyUSB0:38400#ubx –out file://~/test.txt#ubx`

i get the errormsg:

`specify output stream(s)`

how can i understand the documentation of rtklib. it says the following:
[image: rtklib2.4.2-doc]

Answer (score 1):

Your shell is possibly interpreting the hashes in your command as comments. This might work better:

```
./str2str -in 'serial://ttyUSB0:38400#ubx'  ...
```

Also - are you using the right device specification? Additionally, using ~ with sudo might be problematic. Add yourself to the dialout group (or whatever group /dev/ttyUSB0 belongs to) so you can access the serial port without elevated privileges.

Comment: Checked if i'm a member of `dialout` and tried: `sudo ./str2str -in 'file:///dev/ttyUSB0:38400#ubx' –out 'file:///home/user/testlog.ubx' ` but i'm getting still the same error

Comment: why are you still using sudo? You don't need to if your user is a member of dialout. The `file://` specifications look redundant, so how about: `./str2str -in 'serial:///dev/ttyUSB0:38400#ubx' -out ~/testlog.ubx`

Comment: it still throws: `specify output stream(s)`

Comment: sounds like it's very picky with command type and order. Ask here: [str2](https://github.com/tomojitakasu/RTKLIB/issues/99 "str2"), and see if anyone else has repeated the problem here: [RTKLIB](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/RTKLIB "RTKLIB")

Comment: Try `./str2str -in serial://ttyUSB0:38400#ubx –out /home/user/test.ubx`  Also maybe try `cat /dev/ttyUSB0` to test you have working permissions.  I use a line like this in a script: `str2str -in serial://ttyACM0:230400#ubx -out /home/pi/GPS/log/rover.ubx -out tcpsvr://:1888 -c /home/pi/GPS/m8t_5hz_usb.cmd `